# Why is my handler method not triggered when defined as a lambda?

Tags: java, lambda, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-aws

I am defining an `IntegrationFlow` to stream from SFTP to S3 with the DSL syntax this way :

```java
return IntegrationFlows.from(Sftp.inboundStreamingAdapter(remoteFileTemplate)
                        .remoteDirectory("remoteDirectory"),
                e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(POLL, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
                .transform(new StreamTransformer())
                .handle(s3UploadMessageHandler(outputFolderPath, "headers['file_remoteFile']")) // Upload on S3
                .get();
```

```java
private S3MessageHandler s3UploadMessageHandler(String folderPath, String spelFileName) {
        S3MessageHandler s3MessageHandler = new S3MessageHandler(amazonS3, s3ConfigProperties.getBuckets().getCardManagementData());
        s3MessageHandler.setKeyExpression(new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression(String.format("'%s/'.concat(%s)", folderPath, spelFileName)));
        s3MessageHandler.setCommand(S3MessageHandler.Command.UPLOAD);
        return s3MessageHandler;
    }
```

And it works as intended : the file is well uploaded to my S3 bucket. However, I would like to avoid `SPEL` syntax, and inject headers from the message to the `s3uploadMessageHandler` method, this way I could use a simple `ValueExpression` to set the `keyExpression` in the `s3UploadMessageHandler` method.
To do this, I changed

```java
handle(s3UploadMessageHandler(outputFolderPath, "headers['file_remoteFile']")) // Upload on S3
```

to

```java
handle(m -> s3UploadMessageHandler(outputFolderPath, (String) m.getHeaders().get("file_remoteFile"))) // Upload on S3
```

But now this handler doesn't seem to be triggered anymore. There is no errors in the logs, and I know from the logs that the SFTP polling is still working.

I tried to find the reason behind this, and I saw that when entering the handle method in `IntegrationFlowdefinition.java`, the `messageHandler` class type is different : it's an `S3MessageHandler` when called without lambda, and a `MyCallingClass$lambda` when calling with a lambda expression.

What did I miss to make my scenario working ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to handle a message. One is via a `MessageHandler` implementation - this is the most efficient approach and that's done in the framework for channel adapter implementation, like that `S3MessageHandler`. Another way is a POJO method invocation - this is the most user-friendly approach when you don't need to worry about any framework interfaces.

So, when you use it like this `.handle(s3UploadMessageHandler(...))` you refer to a `MessageHandler` and the framework knows that a bean for that `MessageHandler` has to be registered since your `s3UploadMessageHandler()` is not a `@Bean`.

When you use it as a lambda, the framework treats it as a POJO method invocation and there is a bean registered for the `MethodInvokingMessageHandler`, but not your `S3MessageHandler`.

Anyway, even if you change your `s3UploadMessageHandler()` to be a `@Bean` method it is not going to work because you don't let the framework to call the `S3MessageHandler.handleMessage()`. What you do here is just call that `private` method at runtime to create an `S3MessageHandler` instance against every request message: the `MethodInvokingMessageHandler` calls your lambda in its `handleMessage()` and that's all - nothing is going to happen with S3.

The `ValueExpression` cannot help you here because you need to evaluate a destination file against every single request message. Therefore you need a runtime expression. There is indeed nothing wrong with the `new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression()`. Just because we don't have a choice and have to have only single stateless `S3MessageHandler` and don't recreate it at runtime on every request like you try to achieve with that suspicious lambda and `ValueExpression`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Artem Bilan, your explanation is very clear;